# How is this React element's height getting updated?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So I saw this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/708fp9t2/22/) that produces a div element with "textarea textarea--ghost" (non-ghost textarea) as a class.  I see the following code snippet:

```
setFilledTextareaHeight() {
    if (this.mounted) {
      const element = this.ghost;

      this.setState({
        height: element.clientHeight,
      });
    }
  }
```

But that seems to update only the height of the actual textarea box with class ".textarea".  How does the height of the "ghost" element with class "textarea textarea--ghost" get updated? Is there something about the React lifecycle I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 0):

No React magic here. As the jsfiddle mentions:
`Uses a ghost div to measure height.` So the ghost height is measured not set. The height is implicitly specified by the height of the content.

The procedure works by:

1. Leaving the height of the ghost textarea free
2. Setting the value of the ghost textarea to the value of the main textarea
3. Allow the browser to figure out how high to make the ghost textarea to fill the value by rendering it
4. Measure ghost textarea height in JS/React
5. Set height of main textarea

This complicated procedure is mainly needed for the height CSS transition as CSS transitions on height don't work for `100% old height to 100% new height`, so explicit pixel units must be given for the transition to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening like this...

1. The ghost div has a ref defined -

   Line 67:         `ref={(c) => this.ghost = c}`
2. The ghost div is updated with the value of the textarea during its render.

   Line 70: `{this.state.value}`

   This changes the ghost's height.
3. At the same time, during the `onKeyUp` event, the `setFilledTextareaHeight` method uses the reference `this.ghost` which is the DOM element of the ghost div to get the height of the ghost div and set's it as `height` in state.
4. Re-render and presto!

So in a nutshell, the ghost div changes per the value entered in the main text area and its height is then applied to the text area.